# Yolo8 train_batch.jpg output looks weird

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, yolo, yolov8

I have trained my YoloV8 detection model.
After training the model there are plenty of files stored within in the train folder.
One of the files are the train_batch.jpg and the val_batch.jpg.

The images within the train_batch.jpg are cutted of and scrambled.
[image]

The images within the val_batch.jpg looks fine.
[image]

The imagesize of the images within train_batch and val_batch are the same.

Does someone know if this is a problem?

I have tried to change the image sizes and used various batch sizes.

Comment: Probably data augmentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal behavior of yolo training process. Some kinds of image augmentation are applied to diversify the data. You can control it by changing the augmentation parameters of the training process, especially *mosaic, translate, scale*. Default training augmentation parameters are [here](https://docs.ultralytics.com/usage/cfg/#augmentation). But it is most likely to get lower training performance disabling these parameters. So, disabling them only to get fewer 'weird' images as a training batch is not a good idea. Experiment and tune them to get better model performance, default settings are a good starting point.